# Hasura inherited role permission inconsistency

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

I am trying to define two roles in Hasura:

- `role_1`: In `my_table`, can update: `column_A` and `column_B`
- `role_2`: In `my_table`, can update: `column_C`

I want an end user to be able to update `column_A`, `column_B` or `column_C` without specifying a role, so I combine these into an inherited role: `user`.

I receive the following error when uploading the metadata to Hasura:

```
{
  "internal": [
    {
      "reason": "Could not inherit permission for the role 'user' for the entity: 'update permission, table: my_table, source: 'my_source''",
      "name": "user",
      "type": "inherited role permission inconsistency",
      "entity": {
        "permission_type": "update",
        "source": "my_source",
        "table": "my_table"
      }
    }
  ],
  "path": "$.args",
  "error": "cannot continue due to inconsistent metadata",
  "code": "unexpected"
}
```

The `my_table` permissions in my metadata:

```
"update_permissions": [
  {
    "role": "role_1",
    "permission": {
      "filter": ...(check if I can update column_A and column_B)
      },
      "columns": [
        "column_A",
        "column_B"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "role": "role_2",
    "permission": {
      "filter": ...(a different check if I can update column_C)
      },
      "columns": [
        "column_C"
      ]
    }
  }
],
```

Inherited roles config:

```
"inherited_roles": [
    {
      "role_name": "user",
      "role_set": [
        "role_1",
        "role_2"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

If I include all three columns in update permissions / roles, it works fine. However this isn't what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Thanks to jmart on Hasura Discorf for the answer):*

As far as I understand the feature, it's a cascade of checks, not a combination of checks.

So it looks to see if the user has permission to select columns ABC from the first role it has access to, and if not, checks if it has access via any of the other roles.

If none of the roles are inclusive of all requested columns, it will be considered a clash because they are conflicting permission rules.

Comment: Does this mean the error would be resolved if we gave role_1 or role_2 all columns update permission? or any roles don't have to intersect?